# Use conditional operators AND or OR in an IF statement?

Tags: vimscript

This is probably an incredibly simple question, but I did not find any answer so far (I must lack the right sources, and I don't know where to search in vim's help).

I have a condition and I would like it to include 'AND', like

```
if (condition1 .AND. condition2)
   "do what I want you to do
endif
```

but I couldn't find the syntax. Same thing for 'OR'.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Vimscript use C-like operators `&&` and `||`.

You can find description of their usage on [`:h expr2`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr2). Some important points mentioned by the doc are the following

You'll find that the operators can be concatenated and `&&` takes precedence over `||`, so

```
&nu || &list && &shell == "csh"
```

Is equivalent to

```
&nu || (&list && &shell == "csh")
```

Also once the result is known, the expression "short-circuits", that is, further arguments are not evaluated.  This is like what happens in C.

If you use:

```
if a || b
```

The expression will be valid even is `b` is not defined.